# Android: support multiple screen

Tags: android, screen, resolution

I am trying to program to multiple screens.
I currently have two devices:

Samsung Galaxy S2 with a screen of 4 inches: 480x800
density: 1.5
Height (dp): 533.3333
Width (dp): 320.0
screenLayout: 34 = 0010 0010

Samsung Young with a screen of 3.2 inches: 320x480
density: 1.0
Height (dp): 480.0
Width (dp): 320.0
screenLayout: 18 = 0001 0010

So, the devices differ in density and screenLayout (SCREENLAYOUT_LONG_YES vs. SCREENLAYOUT_LONG_NO).

I prepared image buttons in two sizes and put them in drawable-mdpi (for the higher resolution) and in drawable-ldpi (for the lower resolution). The image buttons have the same name.

I also wrote two different layouts, yet, with the same file name and put them in the layout folder (for the higher resolution) and in the layout-small (for the lower resolution).

I left the Java code with no changes, i.e., it doesn't check the resolution for selecting high or low resolution.

The problem is, that the two devices go to the same folder, both in layout and both in drawable.

What am I doing wrong?
What is the right way to handle multiple screen sizes in android?

Thanks!
AJ

Comment: Samsung galaxy S2 is hdpi device so create a folder drawable-hdpi and not drawable-mdpi. Similarly for Samsung Young it will take from drawable-mdpi and not from drawable-ldpi

Comment: You make very important mistake. Folders layout-small, and postfixes -mdpi, ldpi etc don't depends on screen resolution directly.
mdpi - depends on pixels density on the screen and layout-small depends on physical size of the screen. Read here http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html to understand how it works and why you don't need to work with screen resolution.

Comment: You were right @Vaibs - indeed I mixed between the two devices. Also, Demand, I understood this eventually and thanks for the big help! My solution is to use drawable-mdpi and drawable-hdpi and for layouts: layout-mdpi and layout-hdpi. That worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add layout in Every Folder

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml
```

in manifest file

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable=["true"| "false"]
                  android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"]
                  android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="integer"
                  android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
```

and for more detail [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: Thanks @Digvesh. You didn't mention the drawable in your answer. I put different images in drawable-mdpi (for the lower resolution) and in drawable-hdpi for (for the higher resolution). The images have the same names. Yet, the higher resolution layout, picks the drawables from the mdpi folder instead from the hdpi folder. How to handle this?

Comment: drawable-large-mdpi
drawable-large-hdpi(for Nexus 7)

// for 10 inch tablets
drawable-xlarge-mdpi

Comment: thanks! Eventually, I used layout-mdpi and layout-hdpi and it worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just use the wrong folder for your devices.

As you can see in the section of [Range of screen supported](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) the ranges have no strict bounds.

It is important to know which DPI your device have:

- Galaxy S2: 217 dpi
- Samsung Young: 133 dpi

In the section "Using configuration qualifiers" of the posted linke above you have a table where the densities are described:

- ldpi: ~ 120dpi
- mdpi: ~ 160dpi
- hdpi: ~ 240dpi
- xhdpi: ~ 320dpi

So try to put your layout and image from your `mdpi` to your `hdpi` folders and from `ldpi` to `mdpi`.

You also could try to use the [new size qualifiers](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts), where you can define your layout depending on the e.g. smallest width of your device.